# Equation of pair of lines

Tags: analytic-geometry, area

Prove that the pair of lines $6x^2+5xy-4y^2+7x+13y-3=0$ form a parallelogram with the pair of lines $6x^2+5xy-4y^2=0$. Find its area.

My attempt/
I factorized the second equation to get the two lines represented by it:
$$6x^2+5xy-4y^2=0$$
$$6x^2+8xy-3xy-4y^2=0$$
$$(3x+4y)(2x-y)=0$$.

No what should I should next to complete.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other pair would simplify to $(3x+4y+k)(2x-y-l)=0; $
Now area of the parallelogram is $$k*l\over{\sqrt{(3^2+4^2)(2^2+1^2)}}$$

Just find k and l from substitution.

Distance between $(3x+4y+k=0) and (3x+4y=0)$ = $k\over{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}$
Distance between $(2x-y+l=0) and (2x-y=0)$ = $l\over{\sqrt{2^2+1^2}}$

Area of parallelogram = Product of the distances.

Comment: @Win, I could not understand the formula for area.

Comment: @Tim  It is just the distance between the parallel lines.

Comment: @Win, Also just factorizing the equation can we prove that those lines form a ||gm or are there other conditions , too?

Comment: @Iaamuseruser  The fact that $x^2$ coefficient , $xy$ coefficient , and $y^2$ coefficient is the same implies that the lines are parallel.  Else, after factorizing, you get lines which sure are parallel.